# Active class in dropdown php menu

Tags: php

I am using this code in header.php

```
<?php $activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"); ?>
```

This is in navigation

```
<li class="<?= ($activePage == 'about') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="/about/"><strong>About Us</strong></a></li>
<li class="<?= ($activePage == 'contact') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="/contact/"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
```

Here is dropdown code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">It will be active class <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="/Link-1/">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Link-2/">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Link-3/">Link3</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
```

I want to apply active class on this for example if user is on Link1 page Parent menu should be highlighted.

I tried this

```
<li class="dropdown <?= ($activePage == 'Link-1 || Link-2 || Link-3') ? 'active':''; ?>">                 
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/Link-1/">Link-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Link-2/">Link-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Link-3/">Link-3</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </li> </li>
```

Comment: What you have done is right. What's the problem?

Comment: I want to apply active class on parent menu as well. Used or statement but it didnt work.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `PHP` execution but won't `<?php $activePage = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php"); ?>` always return `header` since that's where the code resides?

Comment: It will give page name

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
<?php
if($activePage == 'Link1'){
    echo "Link1";
}elseif($activePage == 'Link2'){
    echo "Link2";
}
?>
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'Link1') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="/Link1/">Link1</a></li>
    <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'Link2') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="/Link2/">Link2</a></li>
    <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'Link3') ? 'active':''; ?>"><a href="/Link3/">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

javascript solution

```
<script>
 $(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
      $(".dropdown-toggle").text($(this).text());
   });
});
</script>
```

you can also use javascript

```
<script>
 $(function(){
       $(".dropdown-toggle").text($(".dropdown-menu .active").text());
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Please see the question again.

Comment: check now has javascript solution

Comment: Something this will be written:<li class="<?= if ($activePage == 'Link-1') ||($activePage == 'Link-2' || ($activePage == 'Link-3') ? 'active':''; ?> dropdown">

Comment: you can romove this php code and use javascript .. check last update

Comment: check http://codepen.io/omarfathy13/pen/NdWGXJ
you must be set first active by php use
 <li class="<?= ($activePage == 'Link1') ? 'active':''; ?>">

Comment: Actually I prefer this method <li class="<?= if ($activePage == 'Link-1') ||($activePage == 'Link-2' || ($activePage == 'Link-3') ? 'active':''; ?> dropdown"> I am missing some bracket because this is returning error.